# “The page address” or “the address of the page”?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Which would be more correct: “The page address” or “the address of the page” in the sentence:

“Check the page address, or use the form below to search the site:”

in the meaning of the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are interchangeable. Neither is more correct than the other.